# Check for duplicate attribute values in xml nodes with XPath 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, duplicates

Good afternoon to everyone.
Encountered difficulties with xpath query, please help.
Here is an xml file.

```
<Payload>
<row IncidentNumber= "PD1"></row>
<row IncidentNumber= "PD1"></row>
<row IncidentNumber= "PD1"</row>
</Payload>
```

My goal is to check via xpath query if in any row node is a duplicate attribute value. Wrote the following xpath query, but it didn't work. What was wrong ?

`boolean(//row/@IncidentNumber[not(. = ./following::row/@IncidentNumber and . = ../preceding::row/@IncidentNumber)])`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This XPath 1.0 [boolean expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans):

```
boolean(/Payload/row[@IncidentNumber=preceding-sibling::row/@IncidentNumber])
```

With this input:

```
<Payload> 
  <row IncidentNumber="PD1"/>  
  <row IncidentNumber="PD1"/>  
  <row IncidentNumber="PD1"/> 
</Payload>
```

Output:

```
true
```

Test in [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/9302f8e3803af9a1c50d840c081a2049)

And this with this input:

```
<Payload> 
  <row IncidentNumber="PD1"/>  
  <row IncidentNumber="PD2"/>  
  <row IncidentNumber="PD3"/> 
</Payload>
```

Output:

```
false
```

Test in [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/3313d9100195efc5f44581920cc501f8)

**EDIT**: proper XPath 1.0 distinct/duplicate idiom. Read as: *"is there any `row` which `@IncidentNumber` attribute is equal to any one preceding?"*

**Do note**: node set comparison are existential comparison. From the spec:

> If both objects to be compared are node-sets, then the comparison will
>   be true if and only if there is a node in the first node-set and a
>   node in the second node-set such that the result of performing the
>   comparison on the string-values of the two nodes is true.

Comment: Changed the attributes of input xml as follows

<Payload>
  <row IncidentNumber="PD1"/>
  <row IncidentNumber="PD2"/>
  <row IncidentNumber="PD3"/>
</Payload>

and used the boolean expression you've  gave and it gave the true ouput, but it's not correct. Could you please advice correct xpath expression ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct XPath

boolean(not(//row[@IncidentNumber = following::row/@IncidentNumber  or  @IncidentNumber = preceding::row/@IncidentNumber ]))